# JComboBox doesn't give the Index

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jcombobox

I can't understand what's wrong.

I have a `JFrame`, with `JTextFields` and `JComboBoxe`s. When I push a button, it has to take the values from the `JTextField`s and pass them to one of the methods, which is chosen in the `JComboBox`, but I can't get the index of the items within the `JComboBox`.

Here is my code:

```
public class eHandler implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        try {

            if (e.getSource() == esc) {
                bx.setText(null);
                by.setText(null);
                bt0.setText(null);
                setVisible(false);
                window window = new window("Расчет напряжений");
                window.setVisible(true);
                window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                window.setSize(600, 650);
            }
            if (e.getSource() == count) {
                double x = Double.parseDouble(bx.getText());
                double y = Double.parseDouble(by.getText());
                double t0 = Double.parseDouble(bt0.getText());


                Integer item = (Integer)ras.getSelectedIndex();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, item);


                        if (item == 0) {
                            double tens = linear(x, y, t0);
                            ltr.setText("Напряжение на данном периоде: " + tens + " Мпа");
                        }
                        if (item == 1) {
                            double tens = squard(x, y, t0);
                            ltr.setText("Напряжение на данном периоде: " + tens + " Мпа");
                        }

                    }

            }//try
        catch(Exception ex){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Введите корректные данные");
            }
        }
 }
```

It's wrong in:

```
Integer item = (Integer)ras.getSelectedIndex();
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, item);
```

Comment: The code you posted looks reasonable so the problem is probably elsewhere in your code. Post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem and post this code in the forum. That is create a simple example with a frame, a combo box and a button. When you click the button it will display the selected index. Once you understand the proper usage, you then debug your real application to see where the problem is.

Comment: i have tried something similar to you, but for me it works totally fine. my code: `JComboBox t1=new JComboBox();
  t1.addItem("test");
  t1.addItem("tsds");
  t1.addItem("tesadfds");
  t1.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){
   @Override
   public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
    if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
     Integer item = (Integer)t1.getSelectedIndex();
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, item);
    }
   }
  });`

remember, that the index starts at 0 not at 1

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answers. But it is wrong that i try to use {Listener} for {ComboBox} in other {Listener}. I made a special {Listener} for {JComboBox}, and that has work. Best regards))